# Can Backbone views have two different events on a single html element

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

In my Backbone view can I bind multiple events to the same element?

```
events:{
      'click .app'    : 'appindex',
      'dblclick .app' : 'launchapp'
},

appindex: function() {
    alert(1);
},

launchapp: function() {
    alert(2);
}
```

After double clicking, it seems the `launchapp` method never fires. Could someone help me understand why?

Comment: off course it works. Just do a double click as fast or try `event.preventDefault()` inside `appIndex` where `event = parameter from callback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet seems to be fine, so I think the problem is that `appindex` shows an alert box after the single click and doesn't allow you to do the double click. Try to replace it with a call to `console.log(...)`. If that still doesn't help try to create a simple jsFiddle for others to test.

Comment: yes, it is the alert() blocking the dblclick method, so i guess you can have two different event on one same html element. thanx